How to Read Excel Form Controls Using Power Automate or Office Scripts?
I have an Excel file that contains various Form Controls, such as buttons, checkboxes, and drop-down lists. I need to read the values and states of these Form Controls programmatically using either Power Automate or Office Scripts in an online environment. However, I am unsure about the proper way to access and retrieve the information from these controls. I would like to know the specific steps or methods required to read the Form Control values using these tools.
I tried searching for documentation and examples related to reading Form Controls using Power Automate and Office Scripts, but I couldn't find any clear or comprehensive solutions. I expected to find a straightforward way to access the Form Controls and retrieve their values, similar to how I would do it using VBA in a desktop environment. However, the online tools seem to have different approaches, and I am unsure about the correct syntax or methods to use. I would appreciate any guidance or code samples that demonstrate how to read Form Controls effectively using either Power Automate or Office Scripts in an online Excel environment.

AFAIK, there isn't an interface to get the value of Form Contrls'. The walkaround solution is using Cell Link of Form contorls, then read the value from cells by Office Script.

Excel Online Business Connector has actions to extract table/listobject contents from an Excel file.
What we have been doing in scenarios like this:

Create separate tables in Excel for all data you need to read.
If you need to retain your checkboxes, use macros to set the selected value to one of your tables. I'd avoid using formulas in Excel if you need to ingest the values to Power Apps / Power Automate.
Use Excel Online Business actions to get the tables and then their content (often row 0 cell 0) in Power Automate.

This way you don't need the hassle with Office Scripts.
